# Salesforce formula based related lists?

Tags: formula, related-list

Is it possible to have a related list that is a formula such as the union of two other related lists?

Comment: Id suggest making your own related list component where you can pass in the SObject, field list and even a query if you choose to and populate your related list this way - it works better and you have more control of the content.

Comment: @Ronnie This would be a good approach to use if I had more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not something you can do. You would necessarily need to write some code to make something like this happen. There's a [few ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/search?type=Ideas&keywords=combined+related) you may want to vote on so you can be notified when/if they come about and to indicate that you want those features.

Comment: I am perfectly fine with writing APEX code and such.

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus You might want to do something like create a custom object that you'd populate with a trigger from either object; the net effect would be a single, combined related list with all the details from both objects. It shouldn't be too hard to build.

Comment: @stdcofox Yes. Using a useless object related to both was ultimately the path I followed.